# SQL table join selection

Tags: sql

I am struggling with a select query I'm trying to create to join two tables which has a 1 to many row ratio.

#### Core Table

```
   id   |   client_id  |   vehicle_code   |       risk       |   ....
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 20     | 2            | C2E              | There is no risk |
```

#### Secondary Table

```
   id   |   LTEQR_id   |   period   |   milage   |   advanced_payments   |   subsequent_payments   |   total   | ....
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10     | 20           | 1 Year     | 2000       | NULL                  | NULL                    | NULL      |
 11     | 20           | 2 years    | 1000       | NULL                  | 23                      | 16000.00  |
```

The issue I am having is selecting the rows based on certain columns being populated or not, I have a query to select all the rows which have a `subsequent_payments` of null

```
SELECT l.id
      ,l.client_id
      ,l.vehicle_code
      ,l.risk
FROM core_table l
INNER JOIN secondary_table p ON p.LTEQR_id = l.id WHERE p.subsequent_payments IS NULL
```

Which works fine for `subsequent_payments` and other columns, but when I try to do the opposite like `IS NOT NULL`, it will still select the row because in the secondary table id 11 has the value 23 for `subsequent_payments` but I want it to only select the row if all rows in the secondary table are not null and I'm struggling to get my head around the logic, so help with this is appreciated I'm open to any solution whether that includes changing the table designs I don't mind.

Comment: what do you mean by `but when I try to do the opposite`

and could you post the structure of your table to check what columns could be null and which have null constraints

Comment: oh sorry I mean `IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a subquery instead of a join

```
SELECT * 
  FROM core_table 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT LTEQR_id 
      FROM secondary_table 
     WHERE LTEQR_id = core_table.id
       AND subsequent_payments IS NULL)
```

Another way would be to `GROUP BY` and use a `CASE`: you would group the records from `secondary_table`, use a case to return 1 or 0 depending on the `NULL` status of the `subsequent_payments` column, which you can then filter with a `HAVING` clause.

It's a bit more complicated than the trivial solution above, but possibly a more performant alternative if you have problems with that.

Comment: `WHERE LTEQR_id = id` would that not make id as an ambiguous column !?!

Comment: Yeah, but not if I still reference `core_table` as `l`

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

You want to select records from a table where exists or not exists a record in another table. So use an EXISTS clause rather than joining the tables.

EDIT: You can also use an IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

if the Secondary table inherit the Unique key of Core table then

```
SELECT * FROM Core A
LEFT JOIN Secondary B ON B.LTEQR_id = A.id
```

it will display each item of Core table have a equal value in Secondary table base on
Secondary.LTEQR_id = Core.id